# Launch RDP exe available on client machine on click of a button present on a WebApplication through Registry

Tags: c#, .net, iis, registry, url-scheme

In one of the requirements, I have to launch RDP exe which is on end user's machine on click of a button available on a website. The IP address to connect RDP will also be passed on the click of the button. The website is hosted on a remote server. This website has been developed in .Net technologies and hosted on IIS. Can we achieve it using registry URL Launcher? If so, can you please let me know how I can do it?

Comment: The termonology you are likely looking for is browser URI scheme and C# protocol handler https://www.joe0.com/2019/01/27/how-create-a-custom-browser-uri-scheme-and-c-protocol-handler-client-that-supports-opening-and-editing-of-remotely-hosted-documents-through-webdav/

Comment: Can you please let me know how it can be done?